# Node Testing How to stub middleware using express-jwt-permissions guard

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jwt, middleware

I am using [express-jwt-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-permissions) and [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) but I want two things:

1. I want to stub the middleware that I am using.
2. I want to pass the guard restricction:

I'll go to share a piece of code:

```
...
MyRoles: guard.check([
    ['admin'],
    ['user']
  ])
...


app.post("/myendpoint", MyRoles, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(1)
}
```

I don't arrive to the `console.log` but, if I remove the middleware `MyRoles` everything works well.

This is my unit test:

```
it("should respond with a 200", function (done) {
    request
      .post("/myendpoint")
      .set("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOi.eyJkYXRhIjp7InVzZ")
      .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function (err, res) {
        ...
        done()
      });
});
```

In the User interface everything works perfectly but I need the two requirements (stub the middleware and pass the middleware by token)

I am hardcoding the token but it didn't pass the middleware, always return `403`.

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you using currently to generate a JWT?  You essentially need to create a fake token that has a `permissions` key, with an array of strings as the permissions.  Then, sign that fake token, which will yield your long encrypted string.  Then use that in place of what you have hard-coded.  I haven't worked with "express-jwt-permissions", but according to their documenation, that ought to be all you need to do.

Comment: thanks, my error was that I forgot to add `app.use(jwt({ secret: Buffer.from(auth.secret, "base64") }));` to my test server